# Custom CheckBox background issue

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I was trying to build a custom `CheckBox`, but I see a black rectangle around it. Why does this happen? And why the second `CheckBox` has the first overlapped?

[image: screenshot]

It looks like there's a black rectangle in a default position of the control. When I add one more `CheckBox`, the second looks like 2 `CheckBox-es` in the same position.

```vb
Public Class mycheckbox
    Inherits CheckBox

    Protected Overrides Sub onpaint(pevent As PaintEventArgs)

        pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(BackColor), Location.X, Location.Y, Width, Height)

        Dim brsh As New SolidBrush(Color.YellowGreen)
        Dim boxside As Integer = CInt(pevent.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font, Width).Height)
        pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(brsh, Location.X, Location.Y, Width, Height)

        If Checked And Enabled Then

            pevent.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.X, Location.X + 1, Location.Y + 1, 18, 18)
            pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(Location.X, Location.Y, 19, 19))
            pevent.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, Brushes.Black, boxside + 15, 11)

        End If

        brsh.Dispose()

    End Sub
End Class
```

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim mcb1 As New mycheckbox
    Dim mcb2 As New mycheckbox

    mcb1.Name = "cb1"
    mcb1.Text = "Hello!!!"
    mcb1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    mcb1.Size = New Size(300, 30)

    mcb2.Name = "cb2"
    mcb2.Text = "Hi!!!"
    mcb2.Location = New Point(10, 50)
    mcb2.Size = New Size(300, 30)

    Me.Controls.Add(mcb1)
    Me.Controls.Add(mcb2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see the screenshot.

Comment: Check the background color of `My.Resources.X`. Should be a `png` image with transparent background. Also, you can omit the first line since you are filling the same area with different color ahead.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I attached the screenshot.

Comment: @JQSOFT Yes, it's a png file.

Comment: I see. You get this because you are using the `Location` property to get `x` and `y` coordinates. Replace the first line with `pevent.Clear(Color.YellowGreen)` and delete the 4th line `pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(brsh, Location.X, Location.Y, Width, Height)`

Comment: You have a host of problems in a few lines of code. 1. See what `Location` actually means (and ClientRectangle, since you're there) 2. Never ever do this: `Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.X ...) `: My.Resources is a Factory, it will generate a **new** Bitmap each time the Paint event is called (many, many times), causing your control to leak resources and handles 3. `FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(BackColor) ...)` never do this. Declare your graphics objects with `Using` statements 4. Use all float measures, not Integer measures, to perform any kind of calculations .5 (Other...)

Comment: 5. `Width`/`Height` include the non-client area. Use the values returned by ClientRectangle or ClientSize 5b. The elements are not positioned in relation to the container's size  6. Using hard-code values to determine the position of graphics objects (Text included here) will produce very different results depending in the current Screen setup, so provide means to scale of the graphics .7 I won't mention DPIAwareness because of a comment constraints 8. Why `pevent`, why? That's very ugly. You can change it to simply `e`, as usual. @JQSOFT I could go on, but I won't :)

Comment: @Jimi Please don't I'm sorry lol. Teasing you is a bad idea. However we've got useful details here. _Merci beaucoup_

Comment: Most welcome d4n183.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your reply. 2. What do you suggest instead of using ```Graphics.Drawimage(My.Resources.X...)```?

Comment: Assign the Resources objects to a `List(Of Image)` (or, better, use a class object with some properties to store the Image objects and other details, as a distinctive `Name` or `ID`, for example and use a `List(Of class)` for storage instead). Or use an ImageList and add the Images to it. Then `Dispose()` of all those objects (including the Images you added to an ImageList, if you used that tool) in the `Dispose()` method. Your Custom Control already implements `IDisposable` (inheriting from CheckBox), you just need to use it.